# Setting the message to disappear after a set period of time or after clicking on any field in the form

Tags: javascript, php

How to make the following message (that the form was sent correctly or not) disappear after five seconds and after clicking any field in the form? What should the code look like for me? Because at this point, after sending the form, the data from it disappears. But the message remains "successful or Error" when writing another message

**PHP**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 


if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
    require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->Username = ".....@.......";
    $mail->Password = "***********";

    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

    if (isset($_POST["userEmail"])) {
        $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["userName"])) {
        $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["userMessage"])) {
        $message = $_POST["userMessage"];
    }
    $mail->SetFrom("....@........"); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($userEmail, $userName);
    $mail->AddAddress(".....@......");

         $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->WordWrap = 80;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);

        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = 'serwer1999676.home.pl';

        if (! empty($_FILES['attachment'])) {
            $count = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
            if ($count > 0) {

                for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
                    if (! empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])) {

                        $tempFileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                        $fileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
                        $mail->AddAttachment($tempFileName, $fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (! $mail->Send()) {
            $message = "Ups :( Error";
            $type = "error";
        } else {
            $message = "Successfull";
            $type = "success";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var valid = true;

            $(".info").html("");
            var userName = document.forms["mailForm"]["userName"].value;
            var userEmail = document.forms["mailForm"]["userEmail"].value;
            var subject = document.forms["mailForm"]["subject"].value;
            var userMessage = document.forms["mailForm"]["userMessage"].value;

            if (userName == "") {
                $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userName").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userEmail == "") {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!userEmail.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
            {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
                $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }

            if (subject == "") {
                $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
                $("#subject").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userMessage == "") {
                $("#userMessage-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userMessage").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;

            $( document ).ready(function(){
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow', function(){
               $('#message').delay(5000).fadeOut(); 
            });
        });
            }
            return valid;
        }

        function addMoreAttachment() {
            $(".attachment-row:last").clone().insertAfter(".attachment-row:last");
            $(".attachment-row:last").find("input").val("");
        }
</script>
```

**html**

```
               <div id="statusMessage"> 
                  <?php
                  if (! empty($message)) {
                  ?>
                  <p class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message'><?php echo $message; ?></p>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
               </div>
```

Comment: How is `validate()` called?

Comment: erm, alas the PHP code you added does not explain how you invoke the `validate` function. Is it as a form `onsubmit` handler? Is it a button click event handler?